# How to stop IIS from decoding URL

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-routing

I use windows 7, IIS 7.5, .NET 4.5.
(For windows 8, IIS 8.5, .NET 4.5, this works).

performing a GET request with URL:

```
http://my.host/api1/MyEntity('%2311282')
```

Problem is that when it gets to servers side code the %23 char is already decoded to '#'
and Uri object thinks it is a fragment char. Win8 machine receives the url with char %23 untouched.

Tried to:
1) use this config setting

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

2) add '/' in the end of the URL

```
http://my.host/api1/MyEntity('%2311282')/
```

3) uninstall the url rewrite 2 module - and reinstall it. also tried to comment the rewrite section in web.config for the module.

Why I want to replicate windows 8 behavior - not decoding the URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Once again quite a bad dup flag imo. Questions are not same. The answer of the other does only say why it is encoded on IIS 7.5, not how to prevent it on IIS7.5, as is asking current question.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look into Rewrite Module.

some information [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Preserving_Original_URL): 
PRESERVING ORIGINAL URL

The URL Rewrite Module preserves the original requested URL path in the following server variables:

HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL – this server variable contains the original URL in decoded format;
UNENCODED_URL – this server variable contains the original URL exactly as it was requested by a Web client, with all original encoding preserved.

hope that helps.

Comment: I checked the variables in the Application_BeginRequest method. They didn't exist there. It had the "URL" variable there with the decoded '#' char in it. any ideas? maybe I looked in the wrong place...

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module  take a look into this.  Usually rewrite rules are placed in appropriate section of web.config

Comment: (1) i tried to comment out the <rewrite> tag. (2) uninstalled url rewrite 2 (3) reinstalled url rewrite 2 (4) uncommented the rewrite section. all these steps didn't help. I think the problem lies beyond url rewrite.

Comment: If you are interested, it's a bug in windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597059/what-decodes-my-encoded-hash-symbol23

Comment: @taminov, Eugen P. solution does work, those server variables do exist in URL rewrite module, but maybe not in asp.net server code. So you may have to use them inside URL Rewrite module, for instance for adding a custom request header containing the value of `{UNENCODED_URL}`. Then you should be able of accessing the custom request header in your .Net code. (Yes, the variable name is quite misleading, should be `UNDECODED_URL` imo.)