# What decodes my encoded hash symbol(%23)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, hash, character-encoding

We noticed that several machines have problems with URLs with hash parameters.

When debugging a request with the URL:
`http://domain.com/Entity(%23{number-here}`

We see in the `Application_BeginRequest` method in the `global.asax`file the URL:
`http://domain.com/Entity(#23{number-here}` in `Url.OriginalString` and the `Url.LocalPath` has `http://domain.com/Entity(` and all the chars after the hash are in `Url.Fragment`.

When running exactly the same application on machines running Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5 it works as expected, the `Url.OrinalString` is `http://domain.com/Entity(%23{number-here}`.

I can't see anything suspisous in the URL rewrite section in the `web.config` or in the IIS configuration.

What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Also for the $ character (%24), I believe..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in System.Web.dll.  It is fixed on Windows 8.1, but we haven't yet rolled out a fix to System.Web.dll on downlevel versions of the operating system.  We're trying to get a fix in for .NET 4.5.x for all supported OSes when the next reliability update comes out.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and offical response! So in the meanwhile what do you suggest us to do? What is the best workaround for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Try querying a different property, such as HttpRequest.Path or HttpRequest.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.  Unfortunately the HttpRequest.Url property is simply too unreliable to use in these scenarios without this bug fix.  (You might be tempted to be clever and use HttpRequest.Url anyway, performing some heuristic check to work around this issue, but I'd advise against this since any workaround might be broken once the actual fix goes out.)

Comment: What about Windows servers? Does this bug influence them as well? All of them? Only some versions? Is there a page we can follow about this bug?

Comment: The fix is currently only in Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012 R2.  Unfortunately there's no public page for our internal bug database.  You can open a Connect bug if you'd like, but they won't give you timelines beyond "it'll likely be fixed in the next reliability update."  (Technically the fix is already checked in so should be picked up automatically by the next reliability update roll-up, but I can't make promises since we've had to roll back fixes before at the last minute due to reports of regressions caused by applications relying on the buggy behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for older OS's until the bug fix is ported back. If you have the luxury of changing the URL, put the term that may contain a hash in a query string parameter, e.g.

```
http://domain.com/?entity=Entity(#23{number-here}
```